# Error State 301 Uploading Images in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

I'm working on a project that is to take a standalone PHP application and move it to WordPress. I've done that and now within WordPress, I am working a particular registration sequence for soccer players to register themselves as players for a team.  At a point in the sequence the user uploads an image of themselves. In the code, it is the file 'select-image.php' that is then attempting to retrieve 'upload-image.php' and edit-image.php' but returning error codes 301 an 302 respectively for each.

I've attached a screenshot showing the network activity when upload-image.php and edit-image.php are attempted to be retrieved.  Neither resource has been moved permanently.  I've also attached a screenhot showing the file is in fact where it is supposed to be on the server.

'select-image.php'

```
<?php
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/required-php-db-connect.php';
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/session-library.php';
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/ACS-library.php';
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/org-library.php';
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/constants-library.php';
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/cart-library.php';
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/division-library.php';
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/team-library.php';
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/user-library.php';
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/form-library.php';
    require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/image-library.php';

// request page post variables here, ensure that  '/libraries/form-library.php' is required above
    $return_page = "";
    if(!empty($_POST["return_page"])){
            $return_page = $_POST["return_page"];
    }

// pre-header php functions (such as ACS activities)
$return_page = "";
if(!empty($_POST["return_page"])){
        $return_page = $_POST["return_page"];
}

$image_mode = get_session_value('image_mode');

if ($image_mode == "") {

    $image_mode = optional_form_item('image_mode'); 
}

if ($image_mode == 'cart_image_mode'){
    $debug_mode = get_session_value('debug_mode');
    $debug_string = "";
    $transaction_id = get_session_value('transaction_id');
    $user_cart = new Cart();
    $user_cart->load_cart($transaction_id);

    $cart_user_info = new cart_user_info();
    $cart_user_info->load_cart_user_info_by_transaction_id($transaction_id);
    $user_id = $cart_user_info->get_cart_user_info_user_id();
} else {

    $user_id = optional_form_item('user_id');
    $team_id = optional_form_item('team_id');
    set_session_value('edit_team_id',$team_id);
}   
set_session_value('image_edit_user_id', $user_id);
// load jquery libraries
    require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/jquery-link-library.php';

// load common css libraries
    require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/css-link-library.php';

    $age_level = get_session_value('age_level');
    if($age_level == 'youth') { 
        require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/bootstrap-library.php';
    }

    //get default season
    $this_season = new Season();
    $season_text = $this_season->display_current_soccer_year();

    $error_message = get_session_value('error_message');
    set_session_value('error_message', null);
// load page specific css libraries
    //require once $_SERVER['document_root'].'/libraries/roster.css';
?>

<!-- all local style references go here.  USE SPARINGLY!  -->

<style type=text/css>
.inactive_step {
    font-weight: normal;
    border:thin #000000 solid;
    display:inline-block;
}
.active_step {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: thin #FF0000 solid;
    display:inline-block;
}

</style>

</head>
<body id='body'>

<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- location of libraries that display data to the page, in the order that the data is displayed -->
    <?php if($age_level == 'youth') { require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/new-menu-bar.php'; } else { require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/menu-bar.php'; } ?>     
    <?php require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/admin-header.php'; ?>
    <div class="main_body">
    <!-- place all content here -->
<?php
    if($age_level == 'youth'){
        echo '<div class="jumbotron" style="margin: auto;">';
    }
    //$image_path = determine_user_image_path($user_id) . "/". get_user_image_file_name($user_id);
    $image_path = get_image_database_path_and_name($user_id);
//1: 
//place ACS and id user info here
//$user_id = get_cart_session_id();

if (empty($error_text)){
//create page output here   
} else {

$display_data = $error_text;        

}
?>
<font style="font-size: 18pt; color: red; align: center;"><?php echo $error_message; ?></font>
<table align="center"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding ="0" width="1000" style="border: solid black 2px; align-self: center; margin: auto;">    
            <?php 
                if ($image_mode == 'cart_image_mode' && $age_level != 'youth'){

                    echo '<tr style = "border-bottom: solid black 2px;">';
                    echo '<td colspan="2" width="1000" align="center">';

                    display_progress(3);
                    echo "</td> </tr>";

                } else if($image_mode == 'cart_image_mode' && $age_level == 'youth') {
                    echo '<tr>
                            <td colspan=2>
                                <h1>Youth Player Registration</h1>
                                <h3>' . trim($season_text) . '</h3>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" width="970" align="center">';
                    display_new_progress(5);
                    echo "</td> </tr>";
                }
            ?>

        <tr>
            <td valign="top" colspan =2 align= 'center' style = "font-size: 18px;"> <!-- BOTH sides of box -->

            <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3 border=0 width=1000 align='center'  >
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                    <br />
                    Click <strong>Browse</strong> to upload your picture or take a picture with your cell phone. 
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    Please select a picture that clearly shows your face. 
                    <br /><br />

                    A small camera picture works MUCH better than a facebook picture. You will have a chance to rotate and crop the picture to select just your face.  If you cannot get a picture to load correctly, it is probably too large in size or dimension.  Use a smaller picture.
                    <br />  <br />


                    You MUST click on the box, shown below on the left (Current Picture), at least once for your picture to show up correctly.<br /><br /> Once you find the file or select your picture, click <strong>Upload Picture</strong>.  
                    <br />
                    <br />

                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr  >
                    <td align="center">

                    <font style="font-size:16px;">Current Picture</font>
                    <br>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" height="200px;" width="200px;"><br />
<br />

                    </td>  

                    <td align="center" >
                    <br />
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="select_image_form" action="/images/upload-image.php" style='font-size: 18px;'>
                    <div class="row">
                      <label for="fileToUpload" style='font-size: 18px;'></label>
                        <button style='height: 70px; width: 250px; font-size:18px;' onclick="document.getElementById('fileToUpload').click();">Click here to select a file or take a pic with your phone</button>
                        <div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
                      <input type="file" accept="capture=camera" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" style='font-size: 18px;'  onchange="var x = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').value;document.getElementById('file_display').value = x; "/>
                        </div><br />

                           File to upload: <input type=text id="file_display" ></input>
                      <input type="hidden" name = "user_id" value = "<?php echo $user_id ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name = "return_page" value = "<?php echo $return_page ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <br />
                      <input type="submit" style='font-size: 18px;' value="Upload This Picture" />
                    </div>
                  </form>           
                    <br>
                    <form action="/images/edit-image-action.php" method="post">
                    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'image_action' value = 'save_old' />
                    <input type='hidden' name='old_path' value = '<?php echo $image_path; ?>' />
                    <input type="submit" style='font-size: 18px;' value="Keep the Current Pic and Skip This Step">
                    </form>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table><br />

            <!-- Add in javascript based 'press button once' feature -->

           </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </div>  <!-- end of main content area -->
<?php require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/user-footer.php'; ?>   
</div>  <!-- end of wrapper -->

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#select_image_form" ).validate({
  rules: {
    fileToUpload: {
      required: true,
      accept: "image/*"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        fileToUpload:{
            required: "You must select a picture to continue",
            accept: "You must select an Image File."
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

'upload-image.php'

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/required-php-db-connect.php';
require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/session-library.php';
require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/ACS-library.php';
require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/user-library.php';
require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/cart-library.php';
require_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/image-library.php';

$debug_mode = get_session_value('debug_mode');
$debug_string = "";
$debug_string .= "<br/> Debug Mode: $debug_mode";
$redirect_url =  "/images/edit-image.php";
//set memory limit to accomodate uploading of 8MB images -TF
ini_set("memory_limit", "512M");

//$user_id = get_cart_session_id();

$image_mode = get_session_value('image_mode');


if ($image_mode == 'admin_image_mode'){
    $user_id =  get_session_value('image_edit_user_id');

}else {
    $transaction_id = get_session_value('transaction_id');
    $cart_user_info = new Cart_user_info(); 
    $cart_user_info->load_cart_user_info_by_transaction_id($transaction_id);

    $user_id = $cart_user_info->get_cart_user_info_user_id();

}
if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] > 0) {
    $debug_string .= UploadException($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']);
} else {
    // array of valid extensions
    $validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');
    // get extension of the uploaded file
    $fileExtension = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], "."));
    // check if file Extension is on the list of allowed ones
    if (in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions)) {
        // we are renaming the file so we can upload files with the same name
        // we simply put current timestamp in front of the file name
        $newName = time() . '_' . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        $destination = '/images/temp/' . $newName;
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot'.$destination)) {

        $manipulator = new ImageManipulator();
        $manipulator->setImageFile($_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . $destination);
        $manipulator->rotate('360');
            // rotate 360 degrees
            //$newImage = rotateImage($image, 360);
            //$manipulator->setImageResource($newImage);
            $manipulator->save($_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . $destination);           

           //redirect_post($redirect_url, 'destination', $destination);
           set_session_value("destination",$destination);
           //header('Location: ' . $redirect_url);

        }
    } else {
        $debug_string .= "  <br/>You must upload an image...<br/>  If the file you attempted to upload was an image, it may not be compatible with this system.  Please try again with another file.";
    }
}


?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>save a picture</title>
<!-- all stylesheets go here -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/login.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/menu.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/common.css" type="text/css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/images/demos.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/images/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- location of libraries that display data to the page, in the order that the data is displayed -->
    <?php require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/logo-header.php'; ?>
    <?php require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/menu-bar.php'; ?>  
    <?php require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/admin-header.php'; ?>
<div class="main_body">


<!-- place all content here -->
<?php
$next_page = $redirect_url;
$debug_string .= "<br/>  Next page: $next_page";
$debug_string .= "<br/> Debug Mode: $debug_mode";
echo $debug_string;

upload_image_button($user_id);
header("location: $next_page"); 
continue_or_debug($next_page, $debug_mode);

?>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you need 'edit-image.php' I can post that.

I don't understand why the error is saying the resource 'upload-image.php' has been permenently moved when it is very clearly sitting in the directory it needs to be in?

What gives?
Thanks,
CM

[Network activity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjiLl.jpg)

[screenshot of resource on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sojwu.jpg)

Comment: 301 and 302 are redirects not error codes

Comment: Yeah I can see at the bottom of upload-image.php you redirect to $next_page. Check your htaccess too

Comment: Thanks George Appleton for responding.  My $next_page variable is set to a $redicrect_url which is the following--$redirect_url =  "./edit-image.php";

What would I need to do in the htaccess file?

Comment: It is saying that edit-image.php has been permanently moved because thats what you've said in your code. You'll likely have to nuke your browser cache once you fix it to get the correct results. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php look at how the location header is described in the documentation. You need to set your response code to use a 301 if you want a non permanent re-direct, but as far as I can tell you don't want a redirect at all. about your .htaccess, just have a look in it for other redirects